# Sniff packets seeing interface name and in/out flag

Tags: linux, networking, nat, wireshark, sniffing

I'm trying to monitor my traffic and installed WireShark as found most recommended tool, on Linux.

However, I found no sure way to see if packet is incoming or outgoing and display interface name (even in packets details interface is always 0). I can guess that info by ip but I want exact info and don't want to be mistaken. Interfaces on `promiscuous` mode already.

E.g. after `ping localhost` with SNAT WireShark monitoring `any` interface (`Linux-cooked` link-layer header) gives one request entry with

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.4, Dst: 127.0.0.1
```

and reply:

`Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1`

where two interfaces are involved and there are two distinct packages for each request and reply IMHO. I cannot see SNAT specifics w/out detailed info.

Are there settings/ways to see

`interface+in/out`

info in WireShark? If not, how do you advice to sniff/monitor?

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html) and its command-line companion capture tools [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) and [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) allow you to specify multiple interfaces to capture on.  So for example, rather than specify *`-i any`* and end up with a Linux Cooked Capture, you can specify *`-i eth0 -i lo`* to capture on both interfaces without losing the per-interface information.  With Wireshark, just *Ctrl-click* each interface you want to capture on from the main page or the *Capture->Options* menu.

And since you're capturing on more than one interface, each interface is assigned a different *Interface id* that is added to the frame data and can even be used to filter packets using the `frame.interface_id` display filter.  For example, if you only want to see the frames for interface ID 0, use `frame.interface_id == 0`.  You can also add this field as a column to more easily see which frame is associated with which interface.

Comment: Thanks! I could not guess to use `Ctrl-Click` to select more than one interface before clicking `Start`, I will try that. Looks like there is no method to distinguish `in` and `out` though, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use tcpdump command to monitor your incoming or outgoing packets.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 (Here you need to specify that which port you want to monitor)
```

And for visualization with Remote IP with packet size you can install **NTOP Tool** on your linux Server